# How can use use non standard font family in Valuebox title and subtitle of shinyDashboard using css file?

Tags: css, r, fonts, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to change the font family of the *title* of my Valuebox to **Nexa Bold**, and the *subtitle* of the valuebox to **Fs Albert**. I know this font family is non standard, so please what should I write in the css file given that I am beginner to HTML and css. 


 Thank you


[image]

**Here is a reproductible example**

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)


header <- dashboardHeader(title="ReproductibleExample")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable=T)
body <- dashboardBody(
   includeCSS("C:/Users/Ccic/Shiny Interface Beta 06_04_2017/Dahsborad/www/custom.css"),
            tags$head(
            tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
            ), 


valueBoxOutput("box_01"),
                  textOutput("print"))

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


server<-shinyServer(function(input, output,session) { 


output$box_01=renderValueBox({
valueBox("Probability ","80%",
          icon("glyphicon glyphicon-oil", lib="glyphicon"), color = "red" )
   })
})
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

and here is my css file :

```
 .box.box-solid.box-success>.box-header {
              font-family: 'Nexa Bold', sans-serif;
                          color:#fff;
                          background:#586F7C
                          }

                          .box.box-solid.box-success{
                          border-bottom-color:#586F7C;
                          border-left-color:#586F7C;
                          border-right-color:#586F7C;
                          border-top-color:#586F7C;
                          }
   .small-box.bg-red { background-color: #AEB4A9 !important; color: #FFFFFF !important; }
```

but it does not work for me !

Comment: pls provide us with a simple app to work with,...

Comment: Hi @BigDataScientist ! Done !

Comment: ok looks better! Just to be sure: I dont see you link the css file in that code? Did you assure having placed it in the correct folder (www). Would you be also fine with css code inside your app without placing it in a seperate file?

Comment: I am using css in a seperate file ! It's in the correct place, I am sure of this becaus I can change other features in my dashboard using css file. Now to solve my problem, I need just two or three code lines to add to my css file in order to : 1-import the file of the new font family , 2- apply this font on my Valuebox title and subtitle. 
Thank in advance